# What is the best way to change the default User Agent for an android app for network request by an external API?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I am currently developing my first app, and I am not that experienced with networking and development in general, so I could use some help. As the question states, I have the need to set a custom User Agent for all network requests, but I am having trouble. I set up an okHTTP Interruption, but that does not seem to be working.

My code for the okHTTP is this:

```
static class UserAgentInterceptor implements Interceptor{
        public String useragent;
        public UserAgentInterceptor(String useragent){
            this.useragent = useragent;

        }
        public UserAgentInterceptor() {
            this(String.format(Locale.US,
                    "%s/%s (Android %s; %s; %s %s; %s)",
                    "MY APP HERE",
                    "3.9",
                    Build.VERSION.RELEASE,                
                    Build.MODEL,
                    Build.BRAND,
                    Build.DEVICE,
                    Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()));
        }

        @NotNull
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        
            Request userAgentRequest = chain.request()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .header("User-Agent", useragent)
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(userAgentRequest);
        }

    }


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        new UserAgentInterceptor();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

I don't think I have any problems with implementing okHTTP into my app (I properly put the implementation in my build.gradle file), so the problem must be elsewhere.

I could be wrong, but I am theorizing it is because my app is not making http requests, but an external API. Once again, let me say that's just my theory as to why it's not working. If that is indeed why I am having this error, could there be a way around this (Retrofit, maybe)?

I appreciate any help with this problem, as well as an explanation to what Retrofit is actually for since I am not too sure on that either. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the interceptor to the client with `addInterceptor`

https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/#application-interceptors

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor())
    .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("http://www.publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
    .header("User-Agent", "OkHttp Example")
    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
response.body().close();
```

Comment: I was seeing similar material earlier, but where I got confused is the url section of building the request. Since I am invoking an external API (Google Admob, I want to change my User-Agent while still receiving ads for testing), I don't have a url to put in there. Instead, I build an AdRequest(), and that API invokes the random URLs that being requested to my network.